# cURL request hangs in docker ubuntu/alpine container

Tags: docker, curl, networking, tcp

I have a digitalocean droplet where i've installed docker. After pulling the ubuntu:18.04 image like this `docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 bash` i've tried to do a curl call on one of my subdomains (i can provide it via a message).

The call looks like this: `curl -vvv -4 api.example.com`

The command hangs with the following output:

`bash
root@bbc3fdec4169:/# curl -vvv -4 api.example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: api.example.com/
*   Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set`

I have no idea why this is failing because doing the same call directly from the digital ocean server works. Also calling the subdomain from my Mac work, and also calling the domain directly in the browser works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a network problem from the container, can you curl www.google.com or ping it?

Comment: Yes, I can ping everything